# How to allow user to quit console app at any time?

Tags: c#

Can someone help me make the option to quit the app at anytime work in this code? Also, I was wondering why I have to hit enter twice for the message `"That is not an integer"` when the user enters a string instead of a number?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace farino_HighLow
{
    public class Game
    {
        // TAKES AND TRACKS USER INPUT
        public void PlayGame()
        {
            // CREATES VARIABLE FOR INPUT FROM THE USER (IF THEY MAKE AN INVALID GUESS OR WANT TO EXIT),
            // THE RANDOM VALUE GENERATED, THE USERS GUESS, AND A COUNTER FOR HOW MANY GUESSES THE USER TAKES
            Random random = new Random();

            int returnValue = random.Next(1, 100);
            string input;
            string line;
            int guess = 0;
            int count = 0;

            Console.Beep(1000, 2000);

            // INSTRUCTS USER WHAT TO DO
            Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1-100");
            Console.WriteLine("Hit Q at any time to exit the game");

            do
            {
                input = Console.ReadLine();

                try
                {
                    guess = Convert.ToInt32(input);
                }
                catch
                {
                    if (input == "Q")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                line = Console.ReadLine();

                if (!int.TryParse(line, out guess))
                    Console.WriteLine("Not an integer!");

                // MAKES SURE USER ENTERS A NUMBER WITHIN THE PARAMETERS OF THE GAME
                // COUNTS THE USER GUESSES
                // TELLS USER IF THEIR GUESS WAS RIGHT OR WRONG AND DIRECTS THEM TOWARDS A BETTER GUESS
                if (guess >= 1 && guess <= 100)
                {
                    if (guess > returnValue)
                    {
                        Console.Beep(100,2000);
                        Console.WriteLine("Guess Again! Your guess is too HIGH");
                        count += 1;
                    }
                    if (guess < returnValue)
                    {
                        Console.Beep(300,2000);
                        Console.WriteLine("Guess Again! Your guess is too LOW");
                        count += 1;
                    }
                    if (guess == returnValue)
                    {
                        Console.Beep(50,2000);
                        Console.Beep(60,2000);
                        Console.Beep(70,2000);
                        Console.WriteLine("You got it RIGHT!!!!!!");
                        count += 1;
                        Console.WriteLine("It took you" + count + "guesses to win the game.");
                    }
                    if (guess < 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid entry");
                    }
                    if (guess > 100)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid entry");
                    }
                }
            } while (guess != returnValue);

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You know `int.TryParse` exists for a reason, right? Don't use exceptions to control application flow - they're slow because they have to trace the entire stack to provide an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try This code

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace farino_HighLow
{
    public class Game
    {
        // TAKES AND TRACKS USER INPUT
        public void PlayGame()
        {
            // CREATES VARIABLE FOR INPUT FROM THE USER (IF THEY MAKE AN INVALID GUESS OR WANT TO EXIT),
            // THE RANDOM VALUE GENERATED, THE USERS GUESS, AND A COUNTER FOR HOW MANY GUESSES THE USER TAKES
            Random random = new Random();

            int returnValue = random.Next(1, 100);
            string input;
            string line;
            int guess = 0;
            int count = 0;

            Console.Beep(1000, 2000);

            // INSTRUCTS USER WHAT TO DO
            Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1-100");
            Console.WriteLine("Hit Q at any time to exit the game");

            do
            {
                input = Console.ReadLine();

                try
                {
                    guess = Convert.ToInt32(input);
                }
                catch
                {
                    if (input == "Q")
                    {
                        //after press Q exit from application
                        return;


                    }
                }

                line = Console.ReadLine();

                if (!int.TryParse(line, out guess))
                    Console.WriteLine("Not an integer!");

                // MAKES SURE USER ENTERS A NUMBER WITHIN THE PARAMETERS OF THE GAME
                // COUNTS THE USER GUESSES
                // TELLS USER IF THEIR GUESS WAS RIGHT OR WRONG AND DIRECTS THEM TOWARDS A BETTER GUESS
                if (guess >= 1 && guess <= 100)
                {
                    if (guess > returnValue)
                    {
                        Console.Beep(100, 2000);
                        Console.WriteLine("Guess Again! Your guess is too HIGH");
                        count += 1;
                    }
                    if (guess < returnValue)
                    {
                        Console.Beep(300, 2000);
                        Console.WriteLine("Guess Again! Your guess is too LOW");
                        count += 1;
                    }
                    if (guess == returnValue)
                    {
                        Console.Beep(50, 2000);
                        Console.Beep(60, 2000);
                        Console.Beep(70, 2000);
                        Console.WriteLine("You got it RIGHT!!!!!!");
                        count += 1;
                        Console.WriteLine("It took you" + count + "guesses to win the game.");
                    }
                    if (guess < 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid entry");
                    }
                    if (guess > 100)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid entry");
                    }
                }
            } while (guess != returnValue);

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if (input == "Q")
                    {
                        return;


                    }  using that code application has quite

Answer (score 0):

Simply use either: `Environment.Exit(0);` or `Application.Exit();`

```
if(condition is true)
{
   Environment.Exit(0);
}
else
{
   //continue
}
```